# python grade calculator to drop lowest score

Tags: python

im working on a python grade calculator for class where i can only use if/else/elif statements to drop the lowest score and then average the scores. this is what i have so far but i dont know how to determine the lowest score from the input using ONLY if/else statements. any help is appreciated!

```
# Input
sName = str(input("Name of person that we are calculating the grades for: "))

iTest1 = int(input("Test 1: "))
iTest2 = int(input("Test 2: "))
iTest3 = int(input("Test 3: "))
iTest4 = int(input("Test 4: "))

sDrop = str(input("Do you wish to drop the lowest grade Y or N? "))

# Test If Statements
if iTest1 <= 0:
    print("Test scores must be greater than 0.")
    raise SystemExit
if iTest2 <= 0:
    print("Test scores must be greater than 0.")
    raise SystemExit
if iTest3 <= 0:
    print("Test scores must be greater than 0.")
    raise SystemExit
if iTest4 <= 0:
    print("Test scores must be greater than 0.")
    raise SystemExit

# Drop Lowest If Statements
if sDrop != "Y" or "N" or "y" or "n":
    print("Enter Y or N to drop the lowest grade.")
    raise SystemExit

# Grade Scale
if score >= 97.0:
    grade = "A+"
elif score >= 94.0 and score <= 96.9:
    grade = "A"
elif score >= 90.0 and score <= 93.9:
    grade = "A-"
elif score >= 87.0 and score <= 89.9:
    grade = "B+"
elif score >= 84.0 and score <= 86.9:
    grade = "B"
elif score >= 80.0 and score <= 83.9:
    grade = "B-"
elif score >= 77.0 and score <= 79.9:
    grade = "C+"
elif score >= 74.0 and score <= 76.9:
    grade = "C"
elif score >= 70.0 and score <= 73.9:
    grade = "C-"
elif score >= 67.0 and score <= 69.9:
    grade = "D+"
elif score >= 64.0 and score <= 66.9:
    grade = "D"
elif score >= 60.0 and score <= 63.9:
    grade = "D-"
else:
    grade = "F"
```

Comment: Suggestion: `if any(score <= 0 for score in (iTest1, iTest2, iTest3, iTest4)):` and then print your error message and exit.

Answer (score 1):

Test the first two to find the smallest of those. Now compare the other two in turn to `smallest` and update `smallest` if necessary.

```
if iTest1 < iTest2:
  smallest = iTest1
else:
  smallest = iTest2

if iTest3 < smallest:
  smallest = iTest3

if iTest4 < smallest:
  smallest = iTest4
```

Of course, all of this is a tedious way to write:

```
smallest = min([iTest1, iTest2, iTest3, iTest4])
```